# Evaluating a Head Gasket Replacement

Tags: engine, volvo, gasket, cylinder-head

**Car:**  1991 Volvo 240

**History:**

There was oil in the coolant expansion tank.  I did a leak down test and could hear air bubbles in the radiator so assumed the head gasket was bad.  I subsequently replaced the head gasket.

**Current status:**

I worry a ***LOT*** and am not confident in my work.  I am not sure that I got the head gasket on correctly.

After replacing the head gasket I did a leak down test and did not hear bubbles in the radiator. I did, however, do a vacuum test at the intake and see a sharp drop in vacuum when I rev the engine. I believe the engine is running a little rich.

I don't notice any "sweet" smell associated with a leaking/blown head gasket.  I tested the O2 sensor with a DMM and the voltage is 0.56 V.

I can test with an oscilloscope, but assume it is OK.

There is sometimes a very small amount of white smoke and water when the car is first started, but then goes away. I should emphasize that the amount of smoke is very small.

I think most people would not notice it, but I do because I am looking for it.

I have not noticed any oil in the coolant expansion tank, coolant in the oil, or coolant in the transmission fluid.

**Next Steps:**

Should I get a kit to test for combustion gasses in the expansion tank?  Would this give me any additional information that a leak down test would not?  Are there any other tests that I can do to make sure I installed the head gasket correctly?

EDIT:  A video of the smoke/fluid from the tailpipe is available [here.](https://flic.kr/p/21MzNzD).  A video of the vacuum at the intake is shown [here](https://flic.kr/p/223Eht5).

Answer (score 1):

There's several tests mentioned on this question
[How to test if head gaskets are blown?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/17378/how-to-test-if-head-gaskets-are-blown/41272#41272)

I'd run a compression test and check how all cylinders are sealing and what variability you find across the block.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  The information is useful, however, it does not address measuring vacuum at the intake.  Is a combustion test at the expansion tank/radiator more sensitive than a leak down test?

Comment: Note that my question now has links to videos of the vacuum at the intake and smoke at the exhaust.